# Android: Using data in network interceptor to do UI-related jobs without breaking the architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

Occasionally APIs can decide to do a ui job before finishing a network call (e.g. showing a webview dialog). Those flags are inside response headers and the value is usually the data, like the url of that webview.

This is the interceptor

```
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        return when (response.code()) {
            200 -> {
                response.headers().forEach { /* do something in ui layer if needed */}
                response;
            }
        }
    }
```

Avoiding EventBus is intended, so I would add a meta data object to the response and then pass it to the repository and parse it in viewmodel, and produce the events for `Activities` and `Fragments`, but is not known to us when this interception is fired so one has to check for all types of events in all of the viewmodels for every api call.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add an `InterceptionMetaData` to the api result.

```
data class InterceptionMetaData(
        val key: String,
        val data: String
)
```

Add this data class to the response (usually the success type, or we can add another Intercepted response type)

```
when (this) {
  is Success -> success?.invoke(this.data, metaData)
  is Error -> error?.invoke(this.error)
  is Loading -> loading?.invoke()
  is Intercepted -> onIntercepted?.invoke(this.data, interceptionMetaDataList)
}
```

in our interceptor we check for response headers (I have used all headers here for demonstration)

```
val interceptionMetaDataList: List<InterceptionMetaData> = response.headers().run {
  names().map { key ->
    get(key)?.let { InterceptionMetaData(key, it) }
  }
}.filterNotNull()
```

and in our repositories we can handle the request and return the actual type to viewmodels.

In viewmodel, another response callback handler can be added (or it can be handled in the already used `success` callback)

```
repository.getNewsList().collectResult(
  onIntercepted = { data, interceptionList ->
    Log.d(NewsViewModel::class.java.simpleName, "getNewsList: $interceptionList")
  },
  success = { data ->
    hideProgress()
    handleData(data)
  },
  error = { error ->
    hideProgress()
    showNoData(error)
  },
  loading = {
    showProgress()
})
```

Usually we have base viewmodels, so we can have our `BaseViewModel` build an event and pass it to our `BaseFragment/BaseActivity` to handle our actual ui job (e.g starting a dialog). That functionality is used where I have put `Log.d`.